# Programmr "replacing and converting Strings" Java

Tags: java

The program below contains an empty method called ‘decrypt()’ which takes a String argument. This method will be invoked with Strings that represent encrypted numbers, you are required to implement the logic that will convert them into a double value. For your convenience we have provided a two dimensional array of characters and the actual number they represent. You can make use of that array if you wish to.

What we expect: If we call the ‘decrypt()’ method with the String “b.aab”, we expect you to return the double value for 1.001. If we call the ‘decrypt()’ method with the String “ab.a”, we expect you to return the double value for 1.0

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.lang.Double;
public class Decrypt {

    private static String conversionTable[][] = {
            {"a", "0"},
            {"b", "1"},
            {"c", "2"},
            {"d", "3"},
            {"e", "4"},
            {"f", "5"},
            {"g", "6"},
            {"h", "7"},
            {"i", "8"},
            {"j", "9"},
    };



    public static double decrypt(String encryptedNumber) {
        ///{
        //write your code here
        //start



        //end
        ///}        
    }



    public static void main(String arg[]){

    Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string to decrypt:");
    String input=scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Number after decryption is:"+decrypt(input));


    }




}
```

I tried a few of varieties but I am not able to understand how can I compare a string with a char type. I don't know even if it is possible or it is correct way to do it. I tried splitting the input string to convert to char using toChar method but then the problem is how to do I compare the char with the 2d array? Also even if I use the nested for loops i'll not able to get the correct solution. I am completely lost here hence this questions.

I have tried following code as well:

```
char[] splitNumber=encryptedNumber.toCharArray();

        for (int i=0;i<splitNumber.length;i++)
        {
            if(splitNumber[i]=conversionTable.charAt(i))
            {
                String str=str+splitNumber[i];
            }
        }
```

But conversionTable.charAt(i) doesn't work

Following is the solution:

```
public static double decrypt(String encryptedNumber) {
        ///{
        //write your code here
        //start
        //char[] splitNumber=encryptedNumber.toCharArray();
        String str="";
        char compare='\0';
        for (int i=0;i<encryptedNumber.length();i++)
        {
            compare=encryptedNumber.charAt(i);
            if (compare=='.')
            {
                str=str+".";
            }
            for(int j=0;j<conversionTable.length;j++)
            {
                if(compare==conversionTable[j][0].charAt(0))
                {
                    str=str+conversionTable[j][1];

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        double dValue=Double.parseDouble(str);
        return dValue;
```

Comment: we need to write the code?? or you have tried something??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site isn't "copy & paste my homework question here, someone please solve it for me". You need to show some effort and explain where you're stuck, what you've tried so far, what baffles you, and so on. Otherwise, it is highly unlikely people will attempt to help you.

Comment: Use `Map` instead of 2-D array, otherwise you need to loop through to get matching key.

Comment: @Prashant I tried a lot of varieties but I am not able to understand how can I compare a string with a char type. I don't know even if it is possible or it is correct way to do it. I tried splitting the input string to convert to char using toChar method but then the problem is how to do I compare the char with the 2d array? Also even if I use the nested for loops i'll not able to get the correct solution. I am completely lost here hence this questions.

Comment: @OriLentz - Please refer to above comment, I tried a few things before posting the question here but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Masud, could you please guide me using 2d array? I don't want to go hashmaps way.

Comment: Could you guys pls help on this and upvote the question?

Comment: @RaghvendraGupta you should supply the code you've written so far and explain your problems, show where you're stuck. Not in a comment, but in the question itself. In its' current form, you'll probably get more downvotes and no upvotes. Show anything you've tried or ask more specific questions (what you've mentioned is easily found on google and SO. For instance, comparing String and char, either use `str.charAt` or convert char to string with `c + ""`).

Comment: @OriLentz, I cannot use str.charAt to compare my char array with 2d array. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RaghvendraGupta I didn't say compare char with 2d array, i referred to what you mentioned above. I cannot give you anymore suggestions without you supplying me with the problematic code, some basic idea of what you're stuck on. I can't solve it for you. Show me where you're stuck and what you've tried, what piece of code baffles you and doesn't compile, and I can try.

Comment: @OriLentz, I just updated my actual question with the code I am trying but it doesn't work. I want some help with working with 2D arrays.

Comment: @RaghvendraGupta `conversionTable` is a 2D array, not a string. You cannot do `charAt` on it, it does not work. If you're trying to access a specific element in the array, then you should `conversationTable[0][0]` to get the specific element (`[0][0]` will return `a` in your example above). What are you trying to compare `splitNumber[i]` to?

Comment: @OriLentz, I am trying to compare splitNumber[i] with all the values present in each row and first column of 2D array conversionTable. For example: splitNumber[i] == conversionTable[0][0], splitNumber[i]==conversionTable[1][0] etc.

Comment: @RaghvendraGupta Okay, great, not that I understand, I've written an answer (so that it's more readable than in a comment). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now that you've explained your problem and where it is you're stuck, I am much more able to help you.

What you're trying to do is compare a `char` to an `array`. You can't do. You need to loop over the array for each character, as such:

```
char[] splitNumber = encryptedNumber.toCharArray();

for (int i=0; i < encryptedNumber.length(); i++) {
    char c = encryptedNumber.charAt(i);
    for (int j=0; j < conversionTable.length; j++) {
        if (c == conversionTable[j][0].charAt(0)) {
            // do whatever you want here
        }
    }
}
```

The inner loop will iterate over the rows of the array and for each row j, will retrieve the value in its' first column (at index 0).

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I finally completed my program. I want to upvote your answer, but because all of you downvoted my question I don't have 15 points which are required to upvote :(

Comment: That's quite alright, I'm just glad I could help. As you'll ask more questions, you'll probably get the hang of it. You now understand better how to ask a question on StackOverflow. Once you explain what your problem is, specifically, you'll get more answers and more upvotes than downvotes.